# PrincipalSearcher not following underlying DirectorySearcher's Filter

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, directorysearcher

I've been working on a bit of code to search Active Directory using C# and the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

The issue I've encountered is that `PrincipalSearcher` cannot do an OR query, so if I wanted to search for users by their email address OR `SamAccountName`, it isn't possible.

To get around this, it seems that `PrincipalSearcher` uses `DirectorySearcher` in the background, so you can access the `DirectorySearcher` and set it up however you'd like (using `GetUnderlyingSearcher`), for some reason though it won't follow the `DirectorySearcher` filter that I've specified.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "localhost");
UserPrincipal usrPrinc = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

PrincipalSearcher searchPrinc = new PrincipalSearcher { QueryFilter = usrPrinc };
DirectorySearcher searchdirectory = searchPrinc.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;

searchdirectory.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(|(name=*admin*)(samaccountname=*admin*)))";
searchdirectory.Sort.PropertyName = "name";
searchdirectory.SizeLimit = 10;

var results = searchPrinc.FindAll();
```

The above returns the correct amount of results based on the `SizeLimit` (10) and does sort it correctly by the `PropertyName`, but it won't use the `Filter` option at all.

Is there any way to set up a `PrincipalSearcher` to use an OR filter (without querying all users and filtering client side) or get it to properly use the `Filter` option?

I have a working method using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` but was looking for the simplicity and methods that a `UserPrincipal` provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can't.

I'm looking a the source code of the .NET Core implementation, but I think we can assume the .NET 4.x implementation is similar, if not exactly the same.

[`PrincipalSearcher.FindAll()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0eb5e7451028e9374b8bb03972aa945c128193e1/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/PrincipalSearcher.cs#L247) calls [`ADStoreCtx_Query.Query()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0eb5e7451028e9374b8bb03972aa945c128193e1/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/AD/ADStoreCtx_Query.cs#L232), which calls an internal method called [`PushFilterToNativeSearcher()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0eb5e7451028e9374b8bb03972aa945c128193e1/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/AD/ADStoreCtx_Query.cs#L115), which starts messing with the filter, overwriting whatever you might have put there.

I've done a bit of searching for an alternative, but there's nothing good. You're better off using `DirectorySearcher` directly.

The `AccountManagement` namespace sometimes makes things easy, but I keep coming back to `DirectoryServices` for reasons like this. Even performance - `AccountManagement` can perform much worse in some cases.